# Simplifying boolean algebra expression $(AB+AC)'+A'B'C$

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$\eqalign{(AB+AC)'+A'B'C&=\overline{(AB+AC)}+\overline A \,\overline BC\\&=(\overline A+\overline B)(\overline A+\overline C)+\overline A\,\overline BC\\&=\overline A+\overline B\,\overline C+\overline A\,\overline BC\\&=\overline A+\overline B(C+C\overline B)}$$

this question i stuck at that,
please show how to continuous simplify it?

Comment: Your last equation is not correct, it would be equal to `!A + !BC + !B!BC`

Comment: !A + !BC + !A!BC??

Answer (score 2):

The last expression is wrong, it could read $\overline A+\overline B(\overline C+\overline AC)$, but **not** like this:
$$\eqalign{(AB+AC)'+A'B'C&=\ldots \\
&=\overline A+\overline B\,\overline C+\overline A\,\overline BC \\
&=\overline A+\overline B\color{red}{(C+C\overline B)}}$$

Here are some equivalent expressions:

$$\eqalign{
(AB+AC)'+A'B'C & = (A(B+C))' + A'B'C \\
& = A' + (B+C)' + A'B'C \\
& = A' + B'C' + A'B'C \\
& = A'(1 + B'C) + B'C' \\
& = A' + B'C' \\
& = A' + (B+C)' \\
& = (A(B+C))' \\
& = (AB+AC)'
}$$

It's up to you to choose which form is 'the simplest'.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$\eqalign{\overline{(AB+AC)} + \overline A \,  \overline B \ C
&=\overline{A(B+C)}+\overline A \,\overline B \, C\\
&=(\overline A +\overline B \, \overline C)+\overline A \, \overline B \, C\\
&=\overline A+\overline B\,\overline C+\overline A\,\overline BC \\
&=\overline A+\overline B(\overline C + \overline A C)\ \text {(wrong above)} }$$

$\ldots$ consider
$$\eqalign {\overline C + \overline A \, C
&= (\overline C + \overline A) \, (\overline C + C) \ \\
&= \cdots }$$